# What links these words?

Tags: knowledge, connections-puzzle

What links the following words:

Brawl

Lost

Dull

Crackpot

Jump

Bunny

Chemistry

Plwmp

Nasty

Comment: Also, should "plwmp" be "plump"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are all

> Place names in the UK

List with links

> Brawl mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strathy)  to the west of Strathy.
>  [Lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost,_Aberdeenshire)
>  [Dull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dull,_Perth_and_Kinross)
>  [Crackpot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crackpot,_North_Yorkshire)
>  [Jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump,_South_Yorkshire)
>  [Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunny,_Nottinghamshire)
>  Chemistry is in Wales, look under "Place Names" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitchurch,_Shropshire)
>  Plwmp, also in Wales, mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llandysiliogogo).
>  [Nasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasty,_Hertfordshire)